# Usage of "would" in context

Tags: meaning

I listened to a program where a person asks another person a question.
After answering the question the first person says: **"you would be exactly right."**
What does **"would"** mean there?
Would it be better to say **"you are exactly right"**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of a *game show* (where the host asks questions and the contestants try to answer) the expression "you would be right" is a kind of [*affectation*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/affectation) that is not not normally used.  It's kind of a response to the *uncertainty* of the answer, as if the contestant had expressed it as a conditional.

> Host:  Question:  What is the capital city of Australia?
>   Contestant A: Is it Sydney?
>   Host:  That is incorrect.
>   Contestant B: Is it Canberra?
>   Host:  That **would be** correct!

The host might also say "that would be incorrect".  Again, not something you would usually say -- unless you're intentionally mimicking a game show host.

> Me: What do I want for dinner?
>   My wife:  Would that be *pizza*?
>   Me:  Ding ding!  That **would be** correct!  Vanna, show the contestant what lovely prizes we have for her today!